# Eclipse for php on Mac OSX 10.5: "Animation Start" error

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-pdt

I am having a terrible time getting Eclipse with php/pdt installed on my older 2006 MacBook running 10.5.8.

I have MAMP installed and running php 5.3.5.  That works fine.  The zend debugger information shows up correctly in phpinfo() and I have dummy.php in the correct location.  127.0.0.1 is allowed in the config file.

I have eclipse itself installed.  I also have tried "Eclipse for php Developers" v3.0.2.

Both installations return errors when I try and run or debug a script.  I am trying to use Zend Debugger.

The error is:

> "Animation Start has encountered a problem".  An Internal error has occurred.
>   An internal error has occurred.
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I have the php executable set as
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php (CLI)

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

The problem with the "Animation Start has encountered a problem" error dialog doesn't have to do with the php scripts but rather is just an UI quirk/error that is irritating and is likely because of a mis-configured dock:icon property on the eclipse.ini (or whatever eclipse product the zend product uses).

1. Find the root executable that launches eclipse-based product.
2. Open up the application executable (.app) package contents
3. Go to the Contents/MacOS/ folder
4. Edit the ini file
5. Make sure that you have this line correctly specificed:
6. `-Xdock:icon=../Resources/<NameofIconFile>.icns`
7. Then restart eclipse/zend

Now you should be able to invoke scripts and not see that invalid error dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You can uncheck "launch in background" in the "common" tab of debug/run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I wanted to simply comment on my "success", following gamerson's answer with a slight adaptation... But it seems like I don't have enough "rep" to do that yet, so here goes ;-)

I had this annoying issue for a little while, and also had a second copy of eclipse for java installed on my macbook. It seems like my eclipse pdt did not contain any .icns files (I did a full recursive search of the dir with "find ."... So I thought, I'll copy it from that other eclipse app I have. And I made sure the ini config file (mentioned by gamerson) had the correct path. And voila! No more of that annoying error popup in eclipse, and also the dock where I had a link to the app now has a nice icon (which before was some ugly "generic" icon with pencils and paper, that all makes sense now). Only downside is that I now have two similar dock icons (the PDT one and the Java one lol) but that is a totally minor annoyance. I guess I could "hack" my dock and give it a funky icon while at it ;-)

Thanks internets!